# Vue3 reactive nested object and optional typings

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm, vuejs3

I seem to have stumbled upon somewhat of a challenge... Maybe a bug in Vue3 with Typescript and the composition api, or maybe im overlooking something.

Im not getting any intellisense in my IDE (Webstorm) if I have an object that is typed as optional:

I have setup this small example:
With this, you would expect that when dotting after .comment you would get "commentAuthor" as a suggestion on that object, but I dont get this. However, if I in my interface tell that comment shouldn't be optional, I get the correct intellisense - If you check out my attached image below, you can see what I mean

```
<template>
  <h2>This is a Vue 3 component!</h2>
  {{ test.post.comment.commentAuthor }}
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from "vue";

interface Comment {
  id: string;
  commentAuthor: string;
  topFriend?: {
    uid: string;
    name: string;
  };
}
interface Post {
  id: string;
  postContent: string;
  comment?: Comment;
}

export interface TestInterface {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  post: Post;
}

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const test = reactive({
      id: "123",
      name: "John doe",
      post: {
        id: "333",
        postContent: "Lorem ipsum",
        comment: {
          id: "444",
          commentAuthor: "Jane Doe",
          topFriend: {
            uid: "555",
            name: "Donald Duck",
          },
        },
      },
    }) as TestInterface;

    return {
      test,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

With optional prop in my interface
[With optional prop in my interface:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtxJ7.png)

Without optional prop
[Without optional prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMQHR.png)

Why is this happening? Im thinking it's often one would have optional objects, so I believe Vue should be able to handle this?

Comment: Can you try with using optional chaining operator? If the object is optional, you should not try to access it's properties without checking it first anyway. - `test.post.comment?.commentAuthor`

Comment: Tried that, dont work... Also tried wrapping it in an v-if="" - That didn't to the trick neither :(

Comment: Well intellisense is something IDE does for you. If it is a bug, it is a bug of IDE (language service it uses for "understanding" Vue files), not Vue itself....

Comment: Dont think it's the editor - Pretty sure...

Comment: Could it have something to do with the ts.config? Is there any option for telling typescript that optional properties should be "available" ? If it's not that by default

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with the IDE, please follow [WEB-50101](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50101) for updates